# Integer Relation Implementation (finding ratio between real numbers)

Tags: c#, .net, math, integer, relation

Can anyone point me to a library or module with a decent integer relation implementation (most likely PSLQ)?

My target platform is .NET (C#), but if there's source code in C/C++, Java, whatever, even a semi-comprehensible algorithm, that would help me a lot.  All I was able to find on Google was some unreadable Mathematica code.

I was able to find an algorithm [here](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/bailey/paper/html/node3.html), and I suppose given several weeks I might be able to muddle through it, but there's got to be somebody out there who's already tackled this problem, given that the algorithm's been the de facto standard for almost 20 years.

Alternatively, if anyone knows of any simpler algorithms I could use, that might help too.  The precision does not have to be ridiculously high and speed is a more important concern than accuracy; I'm half-considering the crudest approach of multiplying by some factor of 10 and looking for an integral GCD, but I don't want to go there until I'm sure I've exhausted any better options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a BSD licensed C++ implementation [here](https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbsoftware/) contained within the 4th package listed, APPREC.

Comment: Hi were you able to compile the package? Could you please, tell how you did it?